# regex match everything up till last number

Tags: c#, regex

I have a couple of strings that look like this

```
EXT. 6TH STREET12B
EXT. HOSPITAL20
EXT. 20TH STREET 40AB
```

How do I match everything up till the last number starts. The result needs to be:

```
EXT. 6TH STREET
EXT. HOSPITAL
EXT. 20TH STREET
```

I'm not a regex expert at all. I tried a few things but nothing seems to come close.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please show what you have tried, even if it didn't work, it may help to see where you went wrong (and sometimes clarify your problem)

Comment: @JohnSaunders The consensus isn't "no, they should not"... It is a little more muddled... And in fact you applied both the first and the second response from that link together (**regex** match...). You could have changed the title to *regex match everything up till last number in C#* and it would have been correct too.

Comment: In the phrase "regex match", "regex" is used as an adjective, not as extra metadata.

Comment: Also, try reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and see if it helps. Especially the bottom part. I wish I could link to just the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the greediness of `*`

```
@".*(?<=\D)(?=\d)"
```

or

```
@".*(?<!\d)(?=\d)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uX1zG3/5)

If you don't want to match the space which exists before the last number.

```
@".*(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\s*\d)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uX1zG3/6)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure string method approach:

```
var digits = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
var trimEnd = digits.Concat(new[]{' ', '\t'}).ToArray(); // if desired
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string line = lines[i];
    int lastIndexOfDigit = line.LastIndexOfAny(digits);
    if (lastIndexOfDigit >= 0)
        line = line.Remove(lastIndexOfDigit).TrimEnd(trimEnd);
    lines[i] = line;
}
```